# cannot resolve public class from other package

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created public class named "KeyClass" in one package and want to import it in another package, but Android Studio cannot resolve it.

[image: Here's KeyClass class]

[image: And Android Studio cannot resolve it, in another package]

Comment: did you try to rebuild project ?

Comment: Add the JAR containing that class in the dependencies.

Comment: Wow, using images in lieu of code snippets sure does make it harder to read, let alone analyze the question.

Comment: That's the problem. I cannot see a code snippet here either. I do see an image of a code snippet, and that's the problem I was highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem - it was about dependencies. Deleted maven central dependency and added:

```
compile project(':rncryptor-native')
```